# Ajax count alert on update database or insert new row

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

please, I need an ajax script that will add to the count of unread messages without a full page refresh and subtract onclick of a message.
Something very similar to inbox messages count in most email clents.
I will truly appreciate any useful help.
Thank you

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/158667)

Comment: I have the php and mysql scripts, I only need some help with the ajax. I'll appreciate it if you can help. Thank you.

Comment: Read that link. Show what you tried and explain where you're stuck/what isn't working.

Comment: @Mat: Nice one, I'll be using that from now on!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's setInterval function to check whether an unread message is available. Example:

setInterval(function() {
    // ajax request to check for unread messages
}, 1000);

The ajax check in the above example will execute in every 1 second (1000 milliseconds). You can change the interval as you like, say 5000 (5 seconds).

Comment: I'm aware of setInterval(), what I need help with really is the ajax request to make. I'll appreciate an explicit help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that can call different php files.

```
function useAjax(url1, area, send1)

{   

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  } else {// code for IE6, IE5

  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

    document.getElementById(area).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }

  }

xmlhttp.open(POST,url,true);


     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


xmlhttp.send(send1);//to send post values "id="+id+"&message="+message"



return false;

}
```

So you could use this function to call "get_messages.php" or "read_message.php" and set the Post vaules accordingly